# How to solve an issue because of ngOnInit() in Angular2+

Tags: angular, logic

I have a flow like - a parent component has three child components. The child's have all the functions coming from the ngOnInit of the Parent component.ie. all the child's work on the basis of parent. The child components work on an `ngOnInit()` of the Parent component i.e. when I navigate to a child component - child's `ngOnInit()` runs and then Parent's `ngOnInit()` runs.

Now I want a function defined in Parent component to not work when inside Parent component but when it goes to the child component it should function. And we cannot segregate that function and put it in only child (which maybe a solution).

So how we decided to work on the above use case is by using a Service SharedComponent which helps as I define the variable globally.

Code:

**facility-definition.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


export interface SharedModel {

    factorFlag:boolean
    }

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class FacilityDefinitionService {

    SharedComponent: SharedModel = {

        factorFlag:false
      }
}
```

**parent.component.ts**

```
export class WorkOrderLimitComponent implements OnInit {


shareData;

constructor( private _woFaclityService: FacilityDefinitionService){

  this.shareData = _woFaclityService.SharedComponent;
}

ngOnInit(){

addSubscribers() {

       //code

                        if(!this.shareData.factorFlag == true){
                        //code
                        });

//code
                        }

}
```

**child.component.ts**

```
export class FactorFormComponent implements OnInit {

ngOnInit() {
this.shareData.factorFlag = true;
}
}
```

But with this global variable factorFlag, initially it is false as defined in Service.ts and when you enter the parent component, it is again false. Now when you go to child component the global variable factorflag becomes true globally, so code in addSubscribers() of parent component becomes true and runs.

Now you again come back to parent component, the factorflag remains true, so the function inside parent component runs. We cannot make factorflag = false in `ngOnInit()` of parent component because when you go to child component, first child component `ngOnInit()` runs and then parent component `ngOnInit()` runs.

How can I resolve the issue? We want `addSubscribers()` to run when only in child not in parent.

Comment: Elaborate your question. Its pretty unclear.

Comment: i have written below also. please check

Comment: For me it's still unclear. Are you running the parent's `ngOnInit` everytime you route to the child component? If so, why?

Comment: @Batajus, Yes Parent's ngOnInit() runs after child's ngOnInit() because it is expressed that way. The child component is dependent on the value selection of the Parent component